# Is it necessary to update Android version?

Tags: updates, operating-system

My Samsung mobile is telling me to update to Android 11, is there really anything that is better than Android 10? I notice the more updates, the more likely it is for others to spy on our data & messages.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, a Q&A site for Android end-users solving their issues. Being a Q&A site, the site has a 1-question-per-post policy to avoid extensive discussion, thus I removed the tangentially related "Edge updated when PC is turned on" (not sure if there's any relevant to Android?). Feel free to post it as a new question.

Comment: Regarding the main topic of "updating Android OS", aside from new features that the user may not care about, I guess one of the most important reasons is the fix to security vulnerabilities (like the monthly security patch).

Comment: The question is not Android 10 or 11 but do you want security patches or not: so do you want to be attackable or not? If you don't want to be attackable you need to install the latest update and those updates are only published for the higher Android version. If you want more control about the OS the only other option is to unlock the device and install a custom ROM like LineageOS (if available for your device model).